# Function inside object loses type safety on return value

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to type my applications plugin functionality. A plugin is defined as an object. Some properties are values, some are functions.

The problem is that functions seems to lose their type safety on their return value. Here's a simplified example:

```
type Something = {
    foo: string,
    bar: string,
    baz: string,
    qux: string
}

type PluginImpl = {
    // foo and bar is handled automatically interanally in the core application
    // which is why it is omitted here from the public api
    somePluginHookFunc: (p: string) => Omit<Something, "foo" | "bar">;
}

const myPlugin: PluginImpl = {
    somePluginHookFunc: (p) => ({
        baz: "asd",
        qux: "sdf",
        sdfsdfsdfsd: "dfg" // this should not be allowed - only "baz" and "qux" should be allowed
    })
}
```

I also made [a running example here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwsAFgSwHYHMoF4oDeAUFKVAGZxwBcUAzsAE6ZYA0JZARgIaO0PNs7MlB4AvfkxbCyARwCuAD0mCsRAL5EioSFAAKAG3lZMASQRgDeQh1IB6OxSpRuGACajeUNHSgpXbgYQHtzywIjcwGgAxtwGBiDeGMAQjK5xCUlQqNDRcIzQ3GCWMZFocBi2UA5QAO7o0SjevvWJaMDNUIjtKR4oqdDkjIjZ-VBg8pwGMS5gaFV0iBCGxpgAElQA1gBi8hjRtAAUYCosAJR4AHxQAPII7QA88Eio0lAARJRw71AAPh88RjvS4Abg0RDyGAYUAQIBWJgwtHhZgsVnwxBEiyQyIwGzgOz2BygxwuuGuhwxIi43AkH24dDc7xkVKgCmUHwZ5CZVUxbnInIFblo7z5WB+NVevjoKDg8gMHgwcA6nEK8TgtWCUAAtF0MJl3uIfgEPmyftLZfLRKqDOrglV1GcNEA)

[image]

How to make TypeScript catch the error at compile time, that `sdfsdfsdfsd` is not a valid property as it is not in the `Omit<Something, "foo" | "bar">` type?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't do that, Typescript is structurally typed.
2. You don't actually want that (even if it's very desirable for the problem you're currently trying to solve), and I'm going to try to convince you.

First things first:

```js
type T = {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}

type U = Omit<T, 'b'>

const foo: T = {
  a: 5,
  b: 'hi',
}

const bar: U = {
  a: 5,
  b: 'hi', // Error!
}
```

So far so good, we've got the type error you were expecting. The problem comes when you try to use it as a function return type:

```js
const f: () => U = () => ({
  a: 5,
  b: 'hi', // fine?
});
```

Why?

Well, I don't know what the reason was. Maybe it was the limitations of control flow analysis in the type checker. Maybe it was a compromise due to Javascript's highly dynamic nature and how it treats objects as grab-bags of random properties.

**Or maybe they realized that in a semver world, that is a *terrible* idea.**

If you're a developer working on an application developed by a single team, this doesn't matter so much. But if you work in a multi-team codebase or you're a library author and that function is part of your public API that means that if you got your wish you can no longer add any properties without a *breaking change*. If Typescript is wrapping a native Javascript API, that means every property added to any native API *anywhere at all* would be a breaking change to *Typescript itself*, and we'd be on TS version 546.7.2 by now.

You *really* don't want that. Don't turn *growth* (this API can now slice *and* dice!) into *breakage*.

There is an exception for direct assignment of object literals as you see in the example above, because that is far more likely to just be a simple bug.

Typescript in general though is structurally typed: if it quacks like a duck and waddles like a duck it's a duck. Your returned object has the properties that match the type, there is no problem. There are plenty of other statically-typed languages that take this approach, even strongly-typed functional languages. Note:

```js
const baz = f();
console.log(baz.b); // Error!
```

When I try to access the 'extra' property on that returned object I rightly get a type error: I would have to add a compile-time legible runtime check to convince the compiler that access is ok:

```js
const isT = (x: any): x is T => {
  return x && (typeof x.a === 'number' && typeof x.b === 'string');
}

if (isT(baz)) {
  console.log(baz.b); // ok
}
```

But crucially one can do this since the 'extra' props come along for the ride. This is *critical* for working with untyped Javascript code.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=32&ssc=2&pln=26&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDeBYAUFKBDAXFAdgK4C2ARhAE4Dc6mpeAzsBQJb4DmNaAvuuqJCgBVBFADyxFsAA8MADRQA5KUUA+PmgDGAe3xMoAM23a8cRKgzY8AVjm0o9JQAsWiuzw069wB1gp4Rc3tcKFt7R0UXN3ReNHQvfQM8AAoASgRVYVE0jKhki0wQsMsIqPduVK543X1SLAAvUQM0rgTtABsIADp27XZkuvqu0krPGp8WBjM8gA88LHwQVLwZqEnYXIKoCghgQgp8KFWAMmO8gQhtAyOurAR4REUiMkpFKFOoC6ub0nvHplYHEUow8cTQLGuyUmMAGDVS6S2bU6PT6sKGIyoUAA9FioNoANYxdBAA)

Comment: Hi Jared.

My reason for having the functions as properties on that object, is for plugin purposes. You define a plugin as an object consisting of props - some as values, some as functions. The reason for the omit is reusing the type with all props, where some of them are automatically internally added by the core app, so on the public api you only need to add the remaining props which has not been omitted. So I don't really have a whole lot of freedom to go away from function as props inside an object. And I'd hate having to use a class for this. So yes I actually think this this, or else..

Comment: .. how would I define that plugin, if I can't use an object?

Comment: @Dac0d3r you could check at runtime and throw an exception if they try to use the same props as the core api. You could define a getter but not a setter for the returned object, or make a setter that throws. You could use unique Symbols for your core property keys. I'm just telling you that your approach of trying to do that at compile-time in the way you're trying to do it won't work, for the reasons given.

Comment: Okay, thanks thanks for a long an detailed answer so far. 
I read it through, but not entirely sure I understand why I'm asking too much from TypeScript here. But I will re-read it until I get it I guess.

Comment: @Dac0d3r like I kinda gestured at in the answer, it doesn't make sense until you start to put yourself in the shoes of the Typescript compiler team. When you start to think about how *you* might solve the problem of "I need to add static typing in a way that doesn't break common Javascript idioms or the ecosystem at large too badly" some of the choices they made make more sense. I think for your particular case I'd consider having everything return an instance of a class (or extended with subclass) that you expose that has getters but not setters for your core properties.

Comment: Jared while I appreciate your answer a lot, I'm waiting with accepting, as I hope there will some other workarounds, that is closer to what fits my code. If I understand you correct your first suggestion was to have plugin implementors to remember to wrap the return value of the `getPartOfMyType` func in a typeguard - which they might forget, so I guess that is why you said I could throw an exception, in which case they'll only realize the error during tests.
Option 2:  use a class. As someone who despises OOP and classes, that would be my last resort, but I hoped it would not come to that.

Comment: @Dac0d3r [you don't have to use a class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDeBYAUFKBzCwoCMBDAJwAoBKALigDsBXAW3wmPQF910BjAexoGc8AMx49qcRKgwES1AKztOaETwB0RYgigBmANzogA). That should keep users from overwriting core properties.

Comment: In my example I forgot to add parameters to the `getPartOfMyType` function. In real life it does have that, so a getter won't work for me, unfortunately. :(

Comment: @Dac0d3r I think you're going to have to either significantly edit your question with a minimal version of your *actual* problem or better yet ask a new follow up question because it would likely invalidate my answer to the question you did ask here.

Comment: I edited the code snippet and question a bit - sorry for that.

Comment: Made a few more edits as it turns out it has nothing to do with the Omit utility type. If I make a normal type the type safety is lost as well.